# Unable to install quandl with either pip or pip3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am unable to install quandl on my windows python 3 installation; it works fine on a 2.7 python version
I have tried pip install quandl and here is the error

```
pip install quandl
Collecting quandl
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000184995217B8>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/quandl/
```

Comment: You seem to have a network issue. Can you access pypi.org?

Comment: Yes I can  access the network and also have an account on pypi.org

Comment: try updating pip to the latest version, and then install quandl

Comment: Could be the firewall... It has nothing to do with having an account, it's a connectivity issue. Double check if you can `curl https://pypi.org`.

Comment: Thanks I fixed the proxy and could install quandl, however my python file is not able to access urls inside it

Comment: Thanks its fixed: in order for python to get the proxy need to do a set
set https_proxy=
Note: it has to be https and not http